# Message boxes with own button texts

Tags: windows, winapi

A lot of applications on Windows show plain message boxes just with "Yes"/"No" or "OK"/"Cancel" buttons. Often it gets worse on non-English Windows' that the text is in English, but the buttons are labeled in the Windows' language.

Is there no simple API to show a message box with own button labels, e.g. "Delete" or "Keep"?

Comment: Sounds like your solution to deal with a language mismatch, due to missing localized resources, is to go [the whole nine yards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_whole_nine_yards) and break the system-provided localization support to match yours. The real solution is to localize **your** resources.

Comment: ... or, if localization to every language is no option, at least keep the application itself in English. My major problem though is the use of Yes/No  because this is bad GUI design. Instead using one (or seldom a few) dialog-specific word(s) would be much better because the user does not always has to read the whole dialog to understand the buttons.

Comment: If the user does not have to read the whole dialog to understand the buttons, then you have put too much text on your dialog. If localization is not an option to you, then please, don't break the part that **is** localized. I'm sure people using Assistive Technologies will hate you for coming up with your own interpretation of being helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable One of the main goals of the task dialog api was to provide a way for the dev to present dialogs with buttons that identify the action clearly. Presenting complex choices and OK/Cancel or Yes/No is a know UI anti pattern. Look at some of the dialogs in all modern OSs. Buttons with names other than the standard set from MessageBox are prevalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like DavidHeffernan said, you should use `TaskDialogIndirect()`, as it natively supports custom buttons.  It is only available on Vista and later, though.

On XP and earlier, you can customize the button captions on a standard `MessageBox()` (or really, any customization you want) by using `SetWindowsHookEx()` to install a thread-local `WH_CBT` hook, or use `SetWinEventHook()`, to obtain the dialog's `HWND` when it is created, then you can manipulate the dialog however you want.  You can use `GetDlgItem()` to get the `HWND` of the individual buttons (and can thus use standard API functions/messages with them), and/or use `GetDlgItemText()` to change their captions.  The CtrlID of each button is the same value that `MessageBox()` returns when that button is clicked.

Comment: Better also hope that MS don't release an OS that implements the dialog in a different way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Obviously, one should use `TaskDialogIndirect()` on modern OS versions, since it natively supports custom buttons.  I would recommend this trick only on XP and earlier where the `MessageBox()` behavior is already locked down.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed such a Win32 function. It is [`TaskDialogIndirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544.aspx). Note that it was introduced in Vista and so if you are still attempting to support XP, then you would need to provide a fall back option for that platform.

Answer (score 0):

This [Projct on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox) provides a pretty good drop in replacement for `MessageBox`, that allows to replace buttons labels among other features.

It is basically a rewritten `MessageBox` function that is a superset of the standard Windows `MessageBox` function. Full source code is provided so you can adapt is easily to your needs if needed.

And it's pure Win32, no MFC is involved here.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Comment: @IInspectable, I agree that this answer is very short, but I didn't want to copy/paste content from codeproject or add more information because: 1) everything that is needed is explained very well in the code project link. 2) Codeproject has been around for years and is unlikely to go away. 3) If codeproject should be discontinued, any context information in the answer would be useless anyway.

Comment: That's a common mistake: The lifetime of a document and that of a hosting site do not have to coincide. Even though stackoverflow may be accessible tomorrow, you could decide to delete your answer, making it inaccessible (to the general public anyway).

Comment: @IInspectable I just expanded the answer a bit. Is it OK now ?

Comment: If you were asking this question, would your answer (without the external resource) provide enough information to help you solve your problem? I believe the answer is *"No"*. Relevant information includes, how the solution is implemented (Does it subclass the standard messages box? Does it implement its own dialog? Does it use the dialog manager's dialog template support? etc.).